# running php command from the cli in parallel

Tags: php, ssh, command-line-interface

i have this shell command, i use it in the crontab

```
for i in {0..10};do /usr/bin/php5-cli -q /my/path/to/file.php --chunk $i;done  > /dev/null 2>&1
```

but each loop step is waiting the previous one to start, and each one takes 5 minutes so it will end after 25 minutes

is there any way to run all the 10 steps in one time? so the whole process will take just 5 minutes

---

I'm using http://php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php for handling the command parameters

Comment: ssh and crontab are completely unrelated. Maybe you meant "shell"

Answer (score 3):

You can run a command in the background simply by putting & sign after it

```
/usr/bin/php5-cli -q /my/path/to/file.php --chunk $i &
```